# PostgreSQL - inconsistent COPY permissions errors

Tags: permissions, pgadmin, postgresql-8.4

I am using the EnterpriseDB pgAdmin III (v. 1.12.1) on a Windows 7, 32-bit machine to work with PostgreSQL databases on a remote Linux server. I am logged in as the user postgres, which allows me to access the $PGDATA directory (in this instance, it is found here: /var/lib/pgsql/data/)

If I log into the server via a terminal, run psql, and use the `\copy` command to import data from csv files into newly created tables, I have no problems.

If I'm in pgAdmin, however, I use the COPY command to import data from csv files into newly created tables.

```
COPY table_name FROM '/var/lib/pgsql/data/file.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER AS ',' csv header
```

Sometimes this works fine, other times I get a permissions error:

> ERROR: could not open file '/var/lib/pgsql/data/file.csv" for reading: Permission denied
>   SQL state: 42501

It is the inconsistency of the error that is confusing to me. When the error arises, I change the file permission to anywhere from 644 - 777, with no effect. I also try moving the file to other folders, e.g., var/tmp/, also with no effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: getting same problem , changed permission to 777 , user to postgres, tried with \ option too, but not able to write anything on file

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the access permissions trough the directories to the file. Postgres user does not have access to your home folder, for example.  The answer is to use a folder all users have access like /tmp, or create one with the correct permissions so any user can access/read/write there, a sort of users shared folder.

Comment: this is the best answer regarding the subject. Solved my problem.

Comment: Yup, copied the files to `/tmp` and adjusted my `COPY FROM` statements appropriately. Not sure if this is a production ready strategy but worked awesome for the one off thing I had to do. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your postgres user still don't have access to your file.

Did you tried the folowing commands ?

chown postgres /var/lib/pgsql/data/file.csv

chmod u+r /var/lib/pgsql/data/file.csv

Answer (score 0):

```
Try \COPY table_name FROM '/var/lib/pgsql/data/file.csv' 
WITH DELIMITER AS ',' csv header
```

Notice the backslash before copy, when you run it with back slash it runs with **user** permissions other wise it just runs as **postmaster** which in the documentation is **deprecated** for recent versions of pg **:|**, anyways this might probably do the trick for ya .

Comment: I probably need to know more from you to answer anything useful, if you just need to get things moving try copying the source file  at C:\Users\Public\Documents