# Providing postgres windows system permission for copy (windows 8)

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

I'm looking to copy CSV files using pgadmin iii. Very new to this.

When I run a "copy" command from the query builder, I'm getting the following error:

```
 ERROR: could not open file 'C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\CDR\\csv1.csv" for reading: Permission denied SQL state: 42501
```

I've found this mentioned a few other places ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263408/postgresql-inconsistent-copy-permissions-errors) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083311/permission-denied-when-trying-to-import-a-csv-file-from-pgadmin), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026536/import-data-from-excel-to-postgresql) for example , and the general fix is to add "postgres" to the file permissions (people also advise moving csv to the public folder, but this causes problems for other reasons).

But when I try to add postgres  to the people with permissions in Windows 8, when I check the name I get an "the object postgres cannot be found" error.

If I add "Everyone" it works, but for obvious reasons I won't want to leave an important folder with "Everyone" access.

Can anyone please advise on how to give postgres permissions in Windows 8?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think you need to double backslashes; PostgreSQL uses SQL standard strings, which don't do backslash escaping. (Unless you use the PostgreSQL extension `E''` string).

Comment: Great! Thanks everyone! The Import tool does work, but I like replicable code, so I was trying to get things to work from the query window. I'll try the "COPY FROM STDIN" variant!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recent versions of PostgreSQL for windows don't use the `postgres` OS account, they use a `NetworkService` system account instead. This is specified in the properties of the PostgreSQL service in Windows. That's presumably the reason of `the object postgres cannot be found` error. Changing the permissions of the file is not really needed anyway.

Recent versions of pgAdmin (1.16+) are able to feed COPY contents from the client to the server without having the server to open the file. Right-click on a table name inside the object browser and check out a menu called `Import`. Internally this will use the `COPY FROM STDIN` variant.

If that's not satisying, there's also the the option of using the `psql.exe` command line tool and its `\copy` command. This command has the same functionality and syntax as the SQL `COPY` command except that it streams the file from client to server instead of having the server open it itself. If you're CLI-oriented, make it your premium choice, it's easier than pgAdmin.

Comment: For how to import a file using the import menu, see [Data Will not import into PG Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67153045/data-will-not-import-into-pg-admin/67164155#67164155).