# Data Will not import into PG Admin

Tags: pgadmin

'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\runtime\psql.exe' file not found. Please correct the Binary Path in the Preferences dialog

This is the response when I get when I try to import data into pg admin. I had the data imported before and it didnt save.

Answer (score 14):

In pgAdmin, simply open File->Preferences, then Paths->Binary Paths.

There, fill in the PostgreSQL Binary Path. In my case, I had to put C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin

[image]

Then, save it before exit, ofc.

Comment: I get fatal error, I did uninstall it so now im trying to figure out what port is viable

Answer (score 0):

shortcut path for the bin folder:
$DIR/../../bin

Answer (score 0):

In pgAdmin, you have to open File->Preferences, then Paths->Binary Paths->PostgreSQL Binary Path.

Simple add following path in

> Windows OS

```
C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\13\\bin
```

Then save the path...